# How to run codeigniter project inside a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am currently creating a new application and trying to migrate from codeigniter to laravel, so I need to use the codeigniter session with laravel (which I already figure it out), but session require a project in the same domain. So I want to do something like this

> domain.com - Laravel Project
>
> domain.com/design - Codeigniter Project

How can I achieve this? I've been trying over and over but nothing come up to work, I ended up deleting both my apache.conf and .htaccess.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to sub domain - design.domain.com that would be much easier. For setting up domain.com/design you have to set up a .htaccess configuration to apply document root to the apache conf

Answer (score 0):

try placing codeigniter on public folder of your laravel